# C# SQL Server Compact Database Login

Tags: c#, authentication, sql-server-ce

I am creating a desktop application in C#. I am creating a Login Form. I have a table named `MyTable` with columns `username` and `password`.

I want to authenticate the user, so I guess I want to know the number of rows affected from SQL query. But every time I got `-1` by executing `ExecuteNonQuery()` method.

My code:

```
string Username = username.Text;
string Password = password.Text;
SqlCeCommand commandSelect = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE username=@username AND password=@password", connection);
commandSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
commandSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Password);
int rows = commandSelect.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show(rows.ToString());
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off changing your SQL to get the count like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable WHERE username=@username AND password=@password
```

And then use `ExecuteScalar()` instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`. This will be less likely to cause you headaches in the future.

Comment: Thank you. You are a life saver.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe ExecuteNonQuery() always returns -1, so don't use that in this case. Steve's answer should do the trick.